# Difficult Katakana Gairaigo シュート

Tags: katakana

Many of us non-native japanese speakers have experienced the difficult of katakana 外来語. 
In this case I am having trouble translating the word **シュート**。　Googling it, it seems that it means "shoot" but it does not make sense. So then I thought, maybe it means "shooter" (which to me sounds シューター)

What do you think? Is there any other way to translate シュート?

(the word refers to a machine parts that redirects things from one part of a machine to a particular place of that machine)

Comment: You're talking about a chute?

Comment: please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as so. Thanks!

Comment: Also, remember that any loan words do not necessarily come from just American or British English, it can be any other language.

Comment: 辞書引いてみられました？　和英と国語辞典を引いたら両方とも一応載ってましたけど・・⇒　https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/シュート (和英辞典)・　https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/104271/meaning/m0u/ (国語辞典)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could have been solved with a quick dictionary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> シュート

shootではなく、Leeboさんのコメントにあるchuteだと思います。
飛行機のemergency escape chute などで使われます。

> the word refers to a machine parts that redirects things from one part of a machine to a particular place of that machine

専門｛せんもん｝用語｛ようご｝ですので、分野｛ぶんや｝によっていろいろな言い方があります。
傾斜台｛けいしゃだい｝、落｛お｝とし樋｛ひ｝、滑降｛かっこう｝斜面路｛しゃめんろ｝、郵便｛ゆうびん｝投下｛とうか｝装置｛そうち｝/レターシュート *letter chute*、降｛お｝ろし樋｛どい｝、荷｛に｝滑｛すべ｝らし、．．．

多分、上記にない場合は、"chute シュート" ではなく、"chuter シューター" と言うことが多いと思います。

## EDIT

日本語訳｛にほんごやく｝を見｛み｝ていますと、質問者｛しつもんしゃ｝が提示｛ていじ｝した定義｛ていぎ｝に加｛くわ｝えて「傾斜路｛けいしゃろ｝あるいは重力｛じゅうりょく｝を利用｛りよう｝して *utilizing inclined paths or gravity*」があると一層｛いっそう｝明確｛めいかく｝になると思｛おも｝います。

> the word refers to a machine parts that redirects things from one part of a machine to a particular place of that machine **by utilizing inclined paths or gravity**

Answer (score 1):

シュート is a term used in soccer too, meaning "a shot on goal".